# What's the point of having more than one tf.Graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

What's the point of having more than one `tf.Graph`?

I'm thinking specifically about hyperparameter tuning of machine learning models, where a model is either a graph on its own, or several models are defined as disconnected components within the same graph.

I understand that having more than one `tf.Session` is bad because task scheduling cannot be done right, so I assume it's possible to have multiple `tf.Graph` objects in one session (though `tf.Session(graph=...)` begs to differ) but what would be the point of doing that instead of having several components with something like `tf.variable_scope` instead? Is it mostly a matter of what gets saved with `tf.train.Saver`, visualized in TensorBoard, and so on? Which method is preferable? Should models share a graph or each have their own for hyperparameter tuning?

It seems simpler to just use `tf.reset_default_graph(); sess = tf.InteractiveSession()` and to forget about both `tf.Graph` and `tf.Session` throughout the rest of the code base. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a single session, then there's no point in having multiple graphs. Session is linked to a graph, so if you try to run an element from another graph, you'll get `xyz is not an element of this graph` error.

It makes sense to have multiple graphs when you have multiple sessions. For instance, suppose you are using distributed TensorFlow, but also want to do some computations locally. You could do something like this

```
local_session = tf.Session("", graph=local_graph)
remote_session = tf.Session("grpc://...", graph=remote_graph)
```

You could potentially use two sessions with the same `tf.Graph` object however, however any additions to this object [will result](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/64edd34ce69b4a8033af5d217cb8894105297d8a/tensorflow/python/client/session.py#L1037) in a `TF_ExtendGraph` call on the next `session.run` even if it's not necessary for that session. In other words, sharing the graph means sending <=2GB graph description to all sessions when the graph is modified.